# Save a buffer to multiple files

Tags: buffers, files, tramp, saving

I have 2 files

```
/home/user/myproject/myfile.el
/ssh:user@myserver.org:/home/user/myproject/myfile.el
```

Content of both of them are same.  I want to make same change in both of them.  I can do it like:

```
1. Edit file in local machine.
2. Push the file to server.
```

Instead, I'd like to connect both files to same buffer.

Comment: Idea: set `after-save-hook` to push the file to server.

Comment: *"I'd like to connect both files to same buffer."* A buffer can visit only one file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Magnar's [multifiles.el](https://github.com/magnars/multifiles.el). You will find it on [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/multifiles).

Like the README says:

> Bind a key to `mf/mirror-region-in-multifile`, let's say `C-!`. Now mark a
>   part of the buffer and press it. A new *multifile* buffer pops up.
>   Mark some other part of another file, and press `C-!` again. This is
>   added to the *multifile*.
>
> You can now edit the *multifile* buffer, and watch the original files
>   change. Or you can edit the original files and watch the *multifile*
>   buffer change.
>
> Saving the *multifile* buffer will save all the original files.